# Cordova Google Map plugin slows down the app performance on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, cordova-plugins, onsen-ui

I am building a hybrid app with Cordova + Onsen UI. Everything runs fine and smoothly until I install plugin.google.maps. After installing the plugin, the entire app becomes quite laggy, even in pages where map is not being used.

Has anyone experienced the same issue ? Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Open platform/android/src/plugin/google/MyPluginLayout.java and GoogleMaps.java

search for line

```
      webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

and change to

```
      webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
```

this boosted my app incredibly. I'm sure this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which maps plugin you use. If your plugin is using Google Maps V3, which is designed for PC browser, which has large memory and better network (than smartphone), it is not suitable for Cordova. On the other hand, you can actually try out implementing [**Google Maps Android API V2**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2) or [**Google Maps SDK for ios**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/).

Answer (score 0):

I really had lot of problems recently (december 2015) using the plugin you mention with cordova and onsen. I crashed with this [problem](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/issues/324).

In the thread you can see a person who worked very hard to solve it but he ended up changing to [Mapbox GL](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/#mapbox-gl). I change to angular google maps which is a slower option but still aceptable.

Hope it helps.

Cheers!